# Removing "Today", "Yesterday", "Last Week" from Outlook Web Access

Tags: outlook-web-app

How do I remove the "grouping" of my email into "Today", "Yesterday", "Last Week", etc. from **Outlook Web Access**. I know how to do this from the actual Outlook program, but I cannot figure out how to do it from the web interface.

I do not want to do it programmatically - I want to do it via the actual **OWA app**.

Please see screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]

I just want my emails listed, one after another...These are NOT conversations. :-)

Perhaps this needs to be moved to another site rather than here...

Thanks!

Comment: Better move this question to http://superuser.com/

Comment: I asked it there too. Do I just delete this then? Was hoping folks here might know....Thanks!

Comment: Just delete it and you're good to go bro.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to customize the current folder view in Outlook. The [CurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864212(v=office.15).aspx) property returns a View object representing the current view.

The [Outlook Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869117.aspx) page in MSDN describes views in depth. Also you may find the [Filtering and Specifying Fields in a View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868051.aspx) and [Sorting Fields in a View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862429.aspx) articles helpful.

Comment: Thanks! But I am trying to do this via the actual OWA interace/options.

Comment: If so, I'd suggest asking non-programming questions on the http://www.superuser.com web site instead. The current site is for developers.